# SQL statement with local (inline) array

Tags: sql

In many languages, one can use inline lists of values, with some form of code similar to this:

```
for x in [1,7,8,12,14,56,123]:
    print x  # Or whatever else you fancy doing
```

Working with SQL for the last year or so, I've found out that even though using such an array in WHERE is not a problem...

```
select * 
from foo
where someColumn in (1,7,8,12,14,56,123) and someThingElse...
```

...I have not found an equivalent form to GET data from an inline array:

```
-- This is not working
select * 
from (1,7,8,12,14,56,123)
where somethingElse ...
```

Searching for solutions, I have only found people suggesting a union soup:

```
select *
from (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 7 UNION ...)
where somethingElse ...
```

...which is arguably, ugly and verbose.

I can quickly generate the UNION soup from the list with a couple of keystrokes in my editor (VIM) and then paste it back to my DB prompt - but I am wondering whether I am missing some other method to accomplish this.

Also, if there's no standard way to do it, I would still be interested in DB-engine-specific solutions (Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc)

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: You are not missing a standard way of doing this.  However, you should be using `union all` and not `union`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Row/Table value constructors* can sometimes be used as a short*ish* hand, for example in MSSQL:

`select * from (values (1),(7),(8),(12)) as T (f)`

The syntax is more complex by necessity than for a simple array-like list passed to `in ()` because it must be able to describe a multi-dimensional set of data:

`select * from (values (1, 'a'),(7, 'b'),(8, 'c'),(12, 'd')) as T (f, n)`

Of course, when you find the requirement to list literal values its often a good idea to stick them in a table and query for them.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this on PostgreSQL, and it worked - but failed in Oracle.